# What's an easier way to do tab completion of many superscripts?

Tags: julia

I know I can type `x\^n` and `tab` to get `xⁿ`.

But how can I input `xᵃ⁺¹` easily, without doing `x\^a tab \^+ tab \^1 tab`.

I tried using brackets, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment, there's no shortcut for expanding extended `latex` superscripts or subscripts via tab expansion. Julia is not actually interpreting the `latex` you write at tab time – all the symbols are hard-coded in the Julia source as a mapping from simple `latex` to unicode (you can find them all [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/latex_symbols.jl)). A better approach might be to define some keyboard shortcuts to write unicode sub/superscripts directly.

Comment: To expand a bit on @freshfruit's comment: `xᵃ⁺¹`  is just the name of a variable, as if you wrote `xap1`; it has no relation to the variable `x`.